# Flink streaming table using kafka source and using flink sql to query

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-flink, flink-streaming, flink-sql

I'm trying to read data from kafka topic into **DataStream** and register **DataStream**, after that use **TableEnvironment.sqlQuery("SQL")** to query the data,  when **TableEnvironment.execute()** there is no error and no output.

```java
public static void main(String[] args){
   StreamExecutionEnvironment env = StreamExecutionEnvironment.getExecutionEnvironment();
   env.setStreamTimeCharacteristic(TimeCharateristic.EventTime);
   env.enableCheckpointing(5000);
   StreamTableEnvironment tableEnvironment = StreamTableEnvironment.create(env);
   FlinkKafkaConsumer<Person> consumer = new FlinkKafkaConsumer(
                                                                "topic",
                                                                 new JSONDeserializer(),
                                                                 Job.getKafkaProperties
                                                               );

  consumer.setStartFromEarliest();
  DataStream<Person> stream = env.addSource(consumer).fliter(x -> x.status != -1).assignTimestampAndWatermarks(new AssignerWithPeriodicWatermarks<Person>(){
      long current = 0L;
      final long expire = 1000L;

      @Override
      public Watermakr getCurrentWatermark(){
         return new Watermark(current - expire);
      }

      @Override
      public long extractTimestamp(Person person){
         long timestamp = person.createTime;
         current = Math.max(timestamp,current);
         return timestamp;
      }
  });
  //set createTime as rowtime
  tableEnvironment.registerDataStream("Table_Person",stream,"name,age,sex,createTime.rowtime");
  Table res = tableEnvironment.sqlQuery("select TUMBLE_END(createTime,INTERVAL '1' minute) as registTime,sex,count(1) as total from Table_Person group by sex,TUMBLE(createTime,INTERVAL '1' minute)");
  tableEnvironment.toAppendStream(t,Types.Row(new TypeInformation[]{Types.SQL_TIMESTAMP,Types.STRING,Types.LONG})).print();
tableEnvironment.execute("person-query");
}
```

when i execute,there was nothing print on console or throw any exceptions;
but if i use **fromCollection()** as a source,the program will print something on the console;
Can you please guide me to fix this?

dependencies:

1. flink-streaming-java_2.11 version:1.9.0-csa1.0.0.0;
2. flink-streaming-scala_2.11 version:1.9.0-csa1.0.0.0;
3. flink-connector-kafka_2.11 version:1.9.0-csa1.0.0.0;
4. flink-table-api-java-bridge_2.11 version:1.9.0-csa1.0.0.0;
5. flink-table-planner_2.11 version:1.9.0-csa1.0.0.0;

Comment: I set an breakpoint on return TriggerResult.FIRE; in Element(Object element,long timestamp,TimeWindow window,TriggerContext ctx) at EventTimeTrigger.class , but never been hit

Comment: Maybe narrow down where the problem is, by first checking if there's actually data in the Kafka topic. Something like `kafka-console-consumer.sh --bootstrap-server kafka:9092 --from-beginning --topic topic`. If that succeeds, then try `stream.print()`.

Comment: By the way, enableCheckpointing is misspelled.

Comment: I set an breakpoint on **.fliter(x -> x.status != -1)** , also i set an breakpoint on **TumblingEventTimeWindows.assignWindows(Object element,long timestamp,WindowAssignerContext context)**,both of **x** and **param:element** has value

Answer (score 0):

In the code where you convert the SQL query's result back to a DataStream, you need to pass `res` rather than `t` to `toAppendStream`. (I can't see how the code you've posted will even compile — where is `t` declared?) And I think you should be able to do this

```java
Table res = tableEnvironment.sqlQuery("select TUMBLE_END(createTime,INTERVAL '1' minute) as registTime,sex,count(1) as total from Table_Person group by sex,TUMBLE(createTime,INTERVAL '1' minute)");
tableEnvironment.toAppendStream(res,Row.class).print();
```

rather than bothering with the `TypeInformation`.

Comment: my fault,The **t** this **res**,And maybe i found whats happened when running,I was using event time,And in Flink SQL i use tumble window  **TUMBLE(createTime,INTERVAL '1' minute)**,As we can see i set **1 minute** to the window,In **TumblingEventWindows.assignWindows(Object element,long timestamp,WindowAssignerContext context)** it use **1 minute** as a window size,And the size using to determine **window start** and **window end**,normally timestamp is numeric like **1591116540000**,but in my case **createTime** field value is **1591237860**, so the window will never been triggered.